# Getting documents with a specific field criteria with criteria value common in all the types

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am trying to get the make mapping for different companies using elastic search in which different companies are defined in the type field and I want to fetch all the makes which occur in a particular company based on which I want to fetch makes makes of other companies common to first search query company.

I am new to elastic search want some assistance with this.

I have tried segregating the problem using elastic search filter and aggregations but still not able to get the values required

DATA for vehicle mappings is:-

```
  {
    "_index" : "vehiclemapping",
    "_id" : "fN1P-GwBjuCNVtK7BNxL",
    "company":"abc1",
    "make":"make1"
   },
   {
    "_index" : "vehiclemapping",
    "_id" : "fN1P-GwBjuCNVtK7BNx2",
    "company":"abc2",
    "make":"make2"
    },
    {
    "_index" : "vehiclemapping",
    "_id" : "fN1P-GwBjuCNVtK7BNx3",
    "company":"abc3",
    "make":"make3"
    },{
    "_index" : "vehiclemapping",
    "_id" : "fN1P-GwBjuCNVtK7BNx4",
    "company":"abc1",
    "make":"make2"
    },
    {
    "_index" : "vehiclemapping",
    "_id" : "fN1P-GwBjuCNVtK7BNx5",
    "company":"abc2",
    "make":"make1"
    },
    {
    "_index" : "vehiclemapping",
    "_id" : "fN1P-GwBjuCNVtK7BNx6",
    "company":"abc2",
    "make":"make3"
    }
```

I am expecting to get result all documents having company = 'abc1' along with other documents having abc1 company makes.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
       {
         "make":"make1"
       },
       {"make":"make2"},
       {"make":"make3"}

Comment: Your requirement seems to be related to a kind of sub-query based solution. However, as of now, elastic search doesn't support sub-queries. (Not sure if it is added in latest version). Also, it would be great if you provide sample expected output.